# Python: Can't seem to decode the textfile

Tags: python, file, character-encoding

I am trying to open the file i.md3 in python. Only the first line is displayed properly.

This file is correct as I can open this in C easily with structures and pointers.

How can I decode this file. I have tried many encoding techniques many of which can show only output of first line.

Without the "encoding=cp850" there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Eclipse Workspace\IGG Project\Main.py", line 40, in <module>
    line = fp1.read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 35: character maps to <undefined>
```

This file is correct as I can open this in C easily with structures and pointers.

Code:

```
fp1 = open("i.md3", encoding="cp850")    

while 1:
    line = fp1.read()
    if not line:
        break
    print (line)
```

First few lines of output is in the link below:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGZhq.png

Comment: Your file contains a non-ascii character with value `0x90`.  Python doesn't know how to decode that value with encoding `cp850`.  You need to fix your input file, or use a different encoding.

Comment: This is my i.md3 file: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcewE.png)

Comment: You need to make a hex dump of your file.  Look at the character in position 35, which is what your error complains about.  Look for the hex value `0x90`.  Then you need to make a choice:  Either change your input file, or use a different encoding.  It's not an ascii file.

Comment: Sucessfully created a hex dump file but was able to find `0x90`. I believe the code is hidden in _struct_ format. Can't change the input file as it is auto generated periodically. Also tried changing encoding, it is still giving me errors with all the encoding techniques. Here is some portion of the hex dump that was created: `b'\xfb\xfe\xfe\x03\x03\x1f\x03\xf5\xff\t\x02\x00\xfd\x00\x07\x85\x00 *\xe2\x`. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Ok, look at the very first byte:  `0xfb`.  That's not an ascii character code.  You're cant's read this as a `cp850` file.  It may not even be character data.  Maybe you should read it as pure data rather than as characters.